# How to Verify if the return of my request on an oracle db is empty or not? C#

Tags: c#, oracle, request, reader

I don't arrive to check if the return of my request on an ORACLE Database is empty or not.

I have tried with :

```
if (myReader["nom_projet"] != DBNull.Value && (myReader["version_projet"] != DBNull.Value)
    console.Writeline("Exist");
else
    console.Writeline("Doesn't exist");
```

I have also tried with :

```
if (myReader.Read())
    console.Writeline("Exist");
else  
    console.Writeline("Doesn't exist");
```

C# code:

```
public Boolean VerifierVersionDejaPresnte(ParseurXML.DonneesGlobales donneGlobale)
 {
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nom_projet, version_projet FROM analyses WHERE nom_projet=:name and version_projet=:version";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("name", donneGlobale._nomProjet));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("version", donneGlobale._version));
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (reader.HasRows)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Exist");
        return true;
      }
     Console.WriteLine("Doesn't exist");
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem is in your code you don't have an "else"!

Then you write "Doesn't exists" each time.
 ... Are you sure `write(Exist)` is OK?

I recommend you try with

```
if (myReader.Read()) {
   Console.WriteLine("Exists");
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("Doesn't Exists");
}
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, here is how to use it:

```
public void CreateMyOracleDataReader(string queryString, string connectionString)
{
  using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
  {
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
        }
    }
    finally {
        reader.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

so you do can just use

```
if (reader.Read())
```